# How to naming "a list of series"?

Tags: java, naming

For example

```
// Java code, I define a variable who type is list to "models"
List<Model> models;
```

This naming convertions work fine on most of the words.

I can do something like

```
for(int i = 0; i < models.size(); i++){
    Model model = model.get(i);
    // Something else
}
```

But If I define "a list of series"

```
List<Series> series;
```

That the code need to change to

```
for(int i = 0; i < series.size(); i++){
    // naming "s" or "ser" I think is not a good idea
    Series s = s.get(i); 
    // Something else
}
```

And I can't distinguish what is variable "series" means.

```
Series series;
List<Series> series;
```

This puzzled me for several years, is how we solve this problem?

**Additional:**
I naming it to "seriesList" on my project. But "models" and "seriesList".. kind of weird, Or I should change models to modelList that they look more uniform

Comment: why not simply use `List<Series> seriesList` ? And it's a self-documenting variable name.

Comment: Yes, I naming it to seriesList on my project. But "models" and "seriesList".. kind of weird, Or I should change models to modelList that they look more uniform

Comment: The naming convention should be consistent in your codes. If you use `SeriesList`, then you should also use `modelList` instead of `models`.

Comment: I want to using "serieses" on my new project. 
Just not sure this is right or not. 
So here I ask. I think you are right. 
"serieses" I think other programmer should be able to understand.

Comment: Perhaps this type of question might be more at home at [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @aaamos Oh, sorry, I don't know that site before. Next time I will post this type of questions there. Thank you for reminding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I too feel strange when dealing with a noun whose plural is the same as the singular, eg

```
List<Series> series;
List<Sheep> sheep; // etc
```

In these cases I manufacture a plural to make the code readable:

```
List<Series> serieses;
for (Series series : serieses) ...
```

Remember, this is coding, not English literature. Code for clarity, not "correct English"

Comment: I want to using "serieses" on my new project. 
Just not sure this is right or not. 
So here I ask. I think you are right. 
"serieses" I think other programmer should be able to understand.

Comment: You cannot be seriouses! Incorrect English does not equal clarity, how can you think this non-existent word makes for "readable" code? -1 from me I'm afraid.

Comment: @aaamos I am serious! Clarity beats grammar and speling every time!

Comment: @aaamos 1. I think "serieses" most simply and clear than "seriesList"
2. when "a list of series" using seriesList, other variables need to be consistent.
Like modelList, brandList, manufacturerList and so on, It is very troublesome.

Answer (score 2):

There are two hard problems in computing, caching and naming things.

This is what I do when I have that problem:

```
List<Series> seriesList;
...
for(Series series : seriesList){
    // Do something else
}
```

Comment: -1 **NEVER** encode the implementation into the name! What if you want to change the collection to a `Set`? Then you'd have to change the variable name to SeriesSet, but the variable isn't a different thing than before. Perhaps `SeriesCollection` might be OK

Comment: @Bohemian: __Always__ be careful with the word __never__. ;-) What if he's done his homework and as per the design he's sure it needs to be a List? There's nothing wrong with a name conveying _what_ something is, that's not violating encapsulation. Refactoring it later if it does need to change is ridiculously simple and shouldn't be avoided, because it then _does_ become something else. +1 from me because that shouldn't be worth a downvote imho.

Comment: `List` is an interface - effectively a set of behaviours, not an implementation. If Tom had suggested `ArrayList<Series> seriesArrayList;` or something similar, then Bohemian would have a valid point.

Answer (score 1):

You may add 'List' as a suffix to List of Objects like

```
List<Series> seriesList;
```